# How to make different permission on document library?

Tags: document-library, permissions, visual-web-part

I want to make document library that can filter view from the user organisation by region. In my Institution has 3 levels that has different level of access file.

The hierarchy of user level can be described as below :

1. Head Office (National)
2. Province
3. District

The library is connected to webpart that I was created. And user is allowing to upload the documents and view based on the region that I was said above.

I want in the District region can upload the documents and view only in the district that the user come from. The Head Office can view all documents, Province can view all district. But district can only view their document only.

How can I achive this matter?

Answer (score 1):

You can split library by folders. One folder for each province, in this folder you can create folders for each districts. On this folders you can specify unique permissions. For example, you can create user groups:

Head Office, Province1, Province2, District1, District2, District3

folder structure:

```
Province1
   District1
   District2
Province2
   District3
```

On the folder Province1 you can set these permissions

```
Province1
   Head Office - contribute
   District1 - read
   District2 - read
   District3 - read

District1
   Head Office - contribute
   District1 - contribute
   District2 - not allowed
   District3 - not allowed
```

etc.

Comment: In my Institution there are 497 Districts and 35 Provinces. How I can receive this solution in the best practices.? And then the permission is not just only the read or contribute only. There are many permission that I have to create If I followed that. I don't want to create manually all the folders and permissions. Am I have to create programmatically?

Comment: You can use PowerShell script